# Android getFragmentByTag returns null when recreated

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to retrieve a fragment on configuration change (like screen rotation)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_tasks);

    // Create/retain AllTasksFragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();       
    allTasksFragment = (AllTasksFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_ALL_TASKS_FRAGMENT);
    if (allTasksFragment == null)
    {
        allTasksFragment = new AllTasksFragment();
        allTasksFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, allTasksFragment, TAG_ALL_TASKS_FRAGMENT).commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_ALL_TASKS_FRAGMENT);
    }
}
```

In this code, findFragmentByTag in the if clause works correctly (tested using eclipse debugger), but the first one always returns null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure the method is called more than once?

Comment: @wastl it is called everytime when I rotate the screen. I tested it by setting a breakpoint.